# Help with asp.net mvc form with multiple models

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nested, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I am having a little trouble figuring how to do this.

here's my scenario

A `User` must create a `IncomeDeclaration` for his `Business`.

But an `IncomeDeclaration` includes many `ActivityIncomeDeclarations` for each `Activity` that his business is on.

I would like my form to include the fields for the new `IncomeDeclaration` as well as the fields for the `ActivityIncomeDeclarations` (which will be obviously related to that `IncomeDeclaration`)....

I know that rubyonrails has a method called "accepts_nested_attributes_for" tgat would probably help me here..

Please help!

Comment: Do you mean it inherits?

Comment: no.. A License has_many Activities... A License has_many (IncomeDeclarations.. yearly basis).. each IncomeDeclaration will have many  Activities as well because the Contributor must give specific details for each Activity when hes declaring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy to achieve. ASP NET MVC is very compositional and you can use templates to achieve this but inheritance is not the way to go.

so solution is for `IncomeDeclaration` to contain a list of `ActivityIncomeDeclarations` and then do this:

```
for(int  i=0; i< Model.Activities.Count; i++)
{
    Html.EditorFor(Model.Activities[i]);  // you need an editor template (and a display template)  for ActivityIncomeDeclarations
}
```

More info:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc2-template-customization
http://www.dalsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2010/04/26/mvc-2-templates/

Comment: Well. This is fine for displaying existing `IncomeDeclaration` activities to edit them. But what if the user decides to delete one of those or add a few new ones?Of course it's possible if you know how to do it, but it's definitely not trivial any more.

Comment: I have one question though... how will the Create Action know to save all this data??.. right now my Create action is just receiving two parameters, int LicenseId and IncomeDeclaration income.. Im not sure if saving the IncomeDeclaration will also save all those ActivityIncomeDeclarations

Answer (score 1):

This blog post of mine can help you lots:

[Asp.net MVC model binding to List<T>](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/09/preparing-list-of-objects-so-they-can.html)

But basically you will provide fields for your `IncomeDeclaration` and then dynamically add `ActivityIncomeDeclaration` fields as needed.

If you want to actually serialize the form you will have to follow instruction provided in the upper blog post.

**But there's the second choice as well if you use jQuery**. You could manipulate a complex JavaScript object that would be a copy of the same server side C# class like:

```
var incDec = {
    Name: ""
    // and other properties
    ActivityIncomeDeclarations: []
};
```

Then while user would be adding those ActivityIncomeDeclarations you'd always simply call

```
incDec.ActivityIncomeDeclarations.push({
    // properties
});
```

Then my other blog post will help you that can convert this object to a Dictionary that jQuery for instance is easily able to process:

[Sending complex JSON objects to Asp.net MVC using jQuery](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/12/sending-complex-json-objects-to-aspnet.html)

By using the prlogin the blog post you could then just easily do:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "someURL",
    type: "POST",
    data: $.toDictionary(incDec),
    success: function(data, status, xhr){
        // process success
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, err){
        // process error
    }
});
```